Finding the minimum of a multivariate function
I have a multivariate function defined by
f[c_] := (1/2) . Transpose[c] . (G[c] + IdentityMatrix[n]) . c - 
  Transpose[c] . M

where G[c] is a matrix of size n * n and M is a column vector of size n * 1. c should be an array of size n * 1. I have to find the minima of f[c] with respect to c with the initial guess of c = ConstantArray[1,n] using QuasiNewton method, so I wrote
FindMinimum[f[z], {z, ConstantArray[1, n]}, Method -> "QuasiNewton"]

but I am getting error that tensors have incompatible shapes
Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{{{3.98299, <<196>>, 3.98299}}, <<249>>}, <<197>>} and {{3.98299,3.99568,3.99858,3.99953,3.99985,3.99995,3.99998,3.99999,4.,4.,<<188>>},<<9>>,<<240>>} have incompatible shapes.

I have checked the dimensions of G[c], M, f[c] and they are all coming out correct. I don't know where is the problem, my guess is I need to modify the FindMinimum command parameters but I am not sure. Thanks for the help.
Edit: I guess its better to give my full code so here it is.
data = {{0.0209, 0.27015}, {0.05996, 0.26012}, {0.09902, 
    0.25781}, {0.13809, 0.2484}, {0.17715, 0.2464}, {0.21621, 
    0.24228}, {0.25527, 0.24271}, {0.29434, 0.23524}, {0.3334, 
    0.23109}, {0.37246, 0.22653}, {0.41152, 0.22938}, {0.45059, 
    0.22343}, {0.48965, 0.21638}, {0.52871, 0.21628}, {0.56777, 
    0.21632}, {0.60684, 0.21225}, {0.6459, 0.20442}, {0.68496, 
    0.21182}, {0.72402, 0.20789}, {0.76309, 0.20011}, {0.80215, 
    0.20145}, {0.84121, 0.19556}, {0.88027, 0.19635}, {0.91934, 
    0.18944}, {0.9584, 0.18961}, {0.99746, 0.18496}, {1.03652, 
    0.18321}, {1.07559, 0.18049}, {1.11465, 0.18176}, {1.15371, 
    0.18364}, {1.19277, 0.17688}, {1.23184, 0.17425}, {1.2709, 
    0.17574}, {1.30996, 0.17022}, {1.34902, 0.17077}, {1.38809, 
    0.17183}, {1.42715, 0.16905}, {1.46621, 0.17015}, {1.50527, 
    0.16674}, {1.54434, 0.16183}, {1.5834, 0.1665}, {1.62246, 
    0.16612}, {1.66152, 0.1563}, {1.70059, 0.1558}, {1.73965, 
    0.15603}, {1.77871, 0.15532}, {1.81777, 0.1622}, {1.85684, 
    0.15456}, {1.8959, 0.15978}, {1.93496, 0.15916}, {1.97402, 
    0.14749}, {2.01309, 0.14654}, {2.05215, 0.13774}, {2.09121, 
    0.14868}, {2.13027, 0.14417}, {2.16934, 0.14678}, {2.2084, 
    0.14451}, {2.24746, 0.1472}, {2.28652, 0.15171}, {2.32559, 
    0.13782}, {2.36465, 0.14514}, {2.40371, 0.13837}, {2.44277, 
    0.13769}, {2.48184, 0.12924}, {2.5209, 0.14703}, {2.55996, 
    0.13402}, {2.59902, 0.12818}, {2.63809, 0.12782}, {2.67715, 
    0.13113}, {2.71621, 0.12521}, {2.75527, 0.1325}, {2.79434, 
    0.12798}, {2.8334, 0.12655}, {2.87246, 0.12637}, {2.91152, 
    0.13851}, {2.95059, 0.11971}, {2.98965, 0.13297}, {3.02871, 
    0.1184}, {3.06777, 0.11851}, {3.10684, 0.12063}, {3.1459, 
    0.11343}, {3.18496, 0.1171}, {3.22402, 0.1226}, {3.26309, 
    0.12416}, {3.30215, 0.11594}, {3.34121, 0.10824}, {3.38027, 
    0.11346}, {3.41934, 0.1211}, {3.4584, 0.11963}, {3.49746, 
    0.10682}, {3.53652, 0.10494}, {3.57559, 0.1028}, {3.61465, 
    0.10458}, {3.65371, 0.11378}, {3.69277, 0.12128}, {3.73184, 
    0.11348}, {3.7709, 0.10779}, {3.80996, 0.10198}, {3.84902, 
    0.11409}, {3.88809, 0.10883}, {3.92715, 0.10037}, {3.96621, 
    0.09063}, {4.00527, 0.0974}, {4.04434, 0.09844}, {4.0834, 
    0.09579}, {4.12246, 0.10854}, {4.16152, 0.10513}, {4.20059, 
    0.10267}, {4.23965, 0.09441}, {4.27871, 0.1094}, {4.31777, 
    0.09307}, {4.35684, 0.10106}, {4.3959, 0.09004}, {4.43496, 
    0.11052}, {4.47402, 0.09944}, {4.51309, 0.08394}, {4.55215, 
    0.09292}, {4.59121, 0.07862}, {4.63027, 0.08725}, {4.66934, 
    0.09424}, {4.7084, 0.09426}, {4.74746, 0.08661}, {4.78652, 
    0.08066}, {4.82559, 0.11172}, {4.86465, 0.08353}, {4.90371, 
    0.0984}, {4.94277, 0.06728}, {4.98184, 0.10221}, {5.0209, 
    0.09977}, {5.05996, 0.09178}, {5.09902, 0.10333}, {5.13809, 
    0.07871}, {5.17715, 0.09899}, {5.21621, 0.08077}, {5.25527, 
    0.09491}, {5.29434, 0.08783}, {5.3334, 0.0757}, {5.37246, 
    0.08865}, {5.41152, 0.08966}, {5.45059, 0.08795}, {5.48965, 
    0.07282}, {5.52871, 0.08705}, {5.56777, 0.06068}, {5.60684, 
    0.11098}, {5.6459, 0.07207}, {5.68496, 0.07319}, {5.72402, 
    0.06959}, {5.76309, 0.07675}, {5.80215, 0.07616}, {5.84121, 
    0.10304}, {5.88027, 0.06411}, {5.91934, 0.071}, {5.9584, 
    0.09302}, {5.99746, 0.06359}, {6.03652, 0.08162}, {6.07559, 
    0.06052}, {6.11465, 0.05886}, {6.15371, 0.05238}, {6.19277, 
    0.087}, {6.23184, 0.05937}, {6.2709, 0.06428}, {6.30996, 
    0.05823}, {6.34902, 0.07888}, {6.38809, 0.07825}, {6.42715, 
    0.08035}, {6.46621, 0.07155}, {6.50527, 0.05685}, {6.54434, 
    0.05015}, {6.5834, 0.04812}, {6.62246, 0.08853}, {6.66152, 
    0.05377}, {6.70059, 0.07265}, {6.73965, 0.08079}, {6.77871, 
    0.06894}, {6.81777, 0.06473}, {6.85684, 0.06795}, {6.8959, 
    0.08318}, {6.93496, 0.06633}, {6.97402, 0.08093}, {7.01309, 
    0.09427}, {7.05215, 0.07511}, {7.09121, 0.08466}, {7.13027, 
    0.11004}, {7.16934, 0.08085}, {7.2084, 0.0694}, {7.24746, 
    0.084}, {7.28652, 0.10564}, {7.32559, 0.05411}, {7.36465, 
    0.08264}, {7.40371, 0.07634}, {7.44277, 0.07977}, {7.48184, 
    0.06492}, {7.5209, 0.08682}, {7.55996, 0.01523}, {7.59902, 
    0.0955}, {7.63809, 0.07506}, {7.67715, 0.1106}, {7.71621, 
    0.06929}};
pk = {1/84, 3/44, 75/364, 1225/1716};
qk = {1, 6, 15, 28};
n = Length[data];
m = 250;
t = Flatten[Take[data, All, {1, 1}]];
M = Flatten[Take[data, All, {2, 2}]];
T1 = Table[0.003 + 0.0321*j, {j, 1, m}];
K = Table[
   Sum[1 - 2 pk[[k]] E^(-qk[[k]]*t[[i]]/T1[[j]]), {k, 1, 4}], {i, 1, 
    n}, {j, 1, m}];
Ee = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], {i, 1, n}];
(*c=Table[1,{i,1,n}];*)
c = ConstantArray[1, n];
H[c_] := 
  Table[HeavisideTheta[
     Flatten[Transpose[Take[K, All, {i, i}]] . c][[1]]]*
    KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, m}];
G[c_] := K . H[c] . Transpose[K]
f[c_] := (1/2) . Transpose[c] . (G[c] + IdentityMatrix[n]) . c - 
  Transpose[c] . M

FindMinimum[f[z], {z, ConstantArray[1, n]}, Method -> "QuasiNewton"]



Can't help much if you don't provide a minimal example that reproduces the error. Add the definitions/values of M, G

Your (1/2) . Transpose[c] and Transpose[c] . M are wrong. You can't transpose a rank1 list a in Mathematica. You should remove the transpose and dot on the other side.

Vector M is coming from data, G is a complicated function of c, I don't think its form will matter much.

Sorry I typed the wrong dimensions for M, I have corrected it.

Here is a working example. As you did not specify G and M, I choose arbitrary tensors for an example. Also note that I use smaller case variable names as you should in MMA:
n = 3;
SeedRandom[1];
c = RandomReal[n];
m = RandomReal[n, n];
g[c_] := Outer[Times, c, c];

f[c_List] := (1/2)   Transpose[c] . (g[c] + IdentityMatrix[n]) . c -  Transpose[c] . m

FindMinimum[Norm[f[z]], {z, ConstantArray[1, n]},  Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]

{0., {z -> {0.0667329, 0.977623, 1.}}}


I am sorry but I am getting this error while running your code:
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value Norm[6. -{1.,1.,1.}.RR[3,3]] is not a real number at {z} = {{1.,1.,1.}}.


Sorry, RR is my privat short cut for RandomReal. I fixed it.

This still does not work for my code, I have given my code explicitly now. Also I have to use QuasiNewton method only. Also I have a couple of questions:


Your code has f[c_List], what's the point of 'List' here.


What is MMA and why I should use lower case variable names only, I am sorry I am new.


Why are you taking Norm[f[z]]?



I just checked my code and it runs fine. I have version Mathematica (MMA) 14.0. In MMA all system functions have uppercase names and it is saver to use lower case variable names.  With the method QuasiNewton I get the somewhat inferior result: "{1.77209*10^-9, {z -> {0.767497, 0.246631, 0.708825}}}. FindMinimum first tries to symbolically simplify the target, therefore I use f[c_List]to prevent that f is evaluated with a symbolic variable.

Yes your code works, my bad. But it does not work for my code, I am getting this error FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value Norm[-24.1585+(1/2).1.52023*10^8] is not a real number at {z} = {{1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,<<188>>}}.

This message does not make sense: Norm[-24.1585+(1/2).1.52023*10^8] is a real number. But as long as you do not give a minimal example it is hard to help you.

I agree with you. Also I have given my code in the question, if you want I can give the data points as well.

Yes, to run the code one needs a minimal data sample.

Updated with the data set.

There are 2 issues here. You can not "Dot" a scalar and a matrix: (1/2) . Transpose[c]... Simply delete the Dot. Further, FindMinimum tries to symbolically simplify  the target function. To prevent this define: f[c_?ListQ] Then start a new kernel and try again. However, the search with 198 variables takes longer than I am willing to wait.

Thank you so much for your input. My system finally gave the output after almost a day of computation. I didn't need to define f[c_?ListQ], just used f[c_List] and it worked. However the dot thing is surprising because 5.IdentityMatrix[3] and 5*IdentityMatrix[3] give me the same result. But anyway thank you so much for your help.

If you write 5.IdentityMatrix then this is interpreted as real number 5. times matrix. However, if there is a space between 5 and Dot, this will not work.
